# Passing a variable between functions using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble passing a variable from one function to another.

This code is from a PhoneGap app that I am working on, the idea is a QR code gets scanned using the **offlineScan** function which calls **checkforOfflineTicket** to check the local storage for ticket validation and returns the variable **ticketCheck** to determine whether the ticket is accepted.

My code below:

```
function checkforOfflineTicket(ticketID){
  var ticketCheck = '1';
  db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
  db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tickets where ticketid=(?)', [ticketID],
    function(transaction, result) {
      if (result.rows.length == '1') {
        if(result.rows.item(0)['status'] == '0'){
          ticketCheck = 'OK';
        }
        else if(result.rows.item(0)['status'] == '1'){
          ticketCheck = 'DUPLICATE';
        }
        else{
          ticketCheck = 'ERROR';
        }
      }
      else{
        ticketCheck = 'NONE';
      }
      alert('the ticket check is '+ticketCheck);
   },function(transaction, error) {
     console.log("Error processing SQL: "+error.message);
  });
  },errorHandler,nullHandler);
  return ticketCheck;
};

function offlineScan(){
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            if(!result.cancelled){
              if(result.format == "QR_CODE"){
                var ticketCheck = 'test';
                var ticketID = result.text; // The ticketID is the full url
                values=ticketID.split('='); // Split it at = to get the tickethash
                one=values[0]; // url
                two=values[1]; // hash
                ticketCheck = checkforOfflineTicket(two);
                alert('ticket check should be '+ ticketCheck);

            } // End if result is QR
          }
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
   );
}
```

The **checkforOfflineTicket** function is currently returning the alert *the ticket check is OK* and then second alert in the **offlineScan** function returns *ticket check should be undefined*. I have tried returning the variable in different places but no matter where I put it it does not get passed to the offlineScan function.

What am I missing? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why the down-vote? I've explained what I'm trying to do, given my code and explained how I've tried to solve it. I've tried to solve the problem myself, have googled for an answer but clearly I'm missing something which is why I've posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by asynchronous method calls in your code. In `checkforOfflineTicket` the function to fetch the result set and doing the alert is called asynchronously to your `offlineScan` function. You have to chain your functions to get the correct order of execution. Following shows one possible way of chaining:

```
function checkforOfflineTicket(ticketID, callback) {
    var ticketCheck = '1';
    db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tickets where ticketid=(?)', [ticketID],
        function(transaction, result) {
            ...
            alert('the ticket check is '+ticketCheck);
            if (callback) callback();
        }, ...
    }
}

function offlineScan(){
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            if(!result.cancelled){
                if(result.format == "QR_CODE"){
                    ...
                    ticketCheck = checkforOfflineTicket(two, function() {
                        alert('ticket check should be '+ ticketCheck);
                    );
                } // End if result is QR
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
   );
}
```